# different random values

Tags: vbscript

I'm generating random values to insert into an array.
For example numbers between 1 and 8, I want to generate an array with this values, without repeating any value.

Here is my code:

```
Function randomValues()
    Dim min
    Dim max
    Dim arr()
    f = 0
    y = 0
    min = 1
    max = 8
    Randomize
    f = (y+1)
    ReDim Preserve arr(f)
    x = Int(Rnd*(max-min+1)) + min
    arr(y) = x
    'LOOP
    Do While UBound(arr) < 8
        x = Int(Rnd*(max-min+1)) + min

        If InStr(arr(f-1), x) <> 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(f)
            arr(f) = x
            f = f+1
        End If
    Loop

    MsgBox Join(arr, "-")
End Function
```

For example the current output is:

*3-6-3-7-8-1-7-6*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is basically drawing numbers from a pool, so I would implement exactly that. Fill data structure with the possible values, and then remove random elements until none are left. I'd use an `ArrayList` for the source data structure, because it allows for removing elements at arbitrary offsets.

```
Set src = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For i = min To max
    src.Add i
Next

ReDim arr(max-1)

i = 0
While src.Count <> 0
    n = Int(src.Count * Rnd)
    arr(i) = src(n)
    src.RemoveAt(n)
    i = i + 1
Wend

WScript.Echo Join(arr, ",")
```

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar, this works very well! God bless you!